# How to return Promise to UI

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am calling a function from a Kendo-grid-column.  That function calls a service to retrieve data from within a Promise.  How do I get the data once resolved, back to the UI?

**Typescript code:**

```
get_AgreementNumber(contactFunc: ContactFunction) {
    var result = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (contactFunc.AgreementId != null) {
         this.agreementService.getBy(contactFunc.AgreementId)
          .toPromise()
          .then(function (result) {
            var res = result.data;
            return resolve(res[0].agreementNumber);
          },
            error => {
              return resolve(null);
            });
      }
    });
    return result;    
  }
```

**Kendo grid cell in ui:**

```html
<kendo-grid-column field="ContactFunctions" title="Agreement/Function" width="200" editor="numeric" [headerStyle]="{'color': 'black','font-weight':'bold'}">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <span *ngFor="let item of dataItem.ContactFunctions;let i = index">
              {{get_AgreementNumber(item)}}
              <label *ngIf="item.AgreementId"><br/></label>
              {{getContactFunction(item)}}
              <label *ngIf="(dataItem.ContactFunctions.length-1)>i"><br/><br/></label>
            </span>
          
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

**This is what I see in grid**

[object Promise]

Comment: you have to bind result to scope, then use it inside your kendo grid

Comment: I don't think scope exists in Angular 7.